# FreeWall nested grid trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to arrange a Freewall layout in something like[image: layout]

Here is the fiddle of the code I'm using (which isn't running properly in JSfiddle - possibly because of window size)

http://jsfiddle.net/tgzL8e04/1/

I'm trying to use this http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/example/nested-grid.html as an example.

Here is the HTML

```
    <div id="guide" >
           <div id = "sceneText" class="sceneText block">
               This is a big block of text
            </div>
           <div id = "contents" data-nested=".level-1"  data-gutterX=10 data-gutterY=10 data-cellW=0.5 data-cellH=0.5>
                <div class="contents block level-1" />
                <div class="contents block level-1" />
                <div class="contents block level-1" />
            </div>   
            <div id = "section"  class="section block" data-nested=".level-1" data-gutterX=10 data-gutterY=10 data-cellW=0.5 data-cellH=0.5 >
                <div class="sectionTitle block level-1" />
                <div class="guideScene level-1" />
                <div class="guideScene level-1" />
                <div class="guideScene level-1" />
                <div class="guideScene level-1" />
            </div>   
             <div id = "section"  class="section block" data-nested=".level-1" data-gutterX=10 data-gutterY=10 data-cellW=0.5 data-cellH=0.5 >
                <div class="sectionTitle block level-1" />
                <div class="guideScene level-1" />
                <div class="guideScene level-1" />
                <div class="guideScene level-1" />
                <div class="guideScene level-1" />
            </div>   
             <div id = "section"  class="section block" data-nested=".level-1" data-gutterX=10 data-gutterY=10 data-cellW=0.5 data-cellH=0.5 >
                <div class="sectionTitle block level-1" />
                <div class="guideScene level-1" />
                <div class="guideScene level-1" />
                <div class="guideScene level-1" />
                <div class="guideScene level-1" />
            </div>   
        </div>
```

And here is the script

```
    $(function() {
            $("#guide").each(function() {
         $(function() {
                var wall = new freewall("#guide");
                wall.reset({
                    selector: '.section',
                    cellW: 200,
                    cellH: 200,
                    fixSize: 5,
                    gutterY: 20,
                    gutterX: 150,
                    animate: true
                });

                wall.reset({
                    selector: '.block',
                    cellW: 200,
                    cellH: 100,
                    gutterY: 20,
                    gutterX: 50,
                    animate: true,
                    onResize: function() {
                        wall.fitHeight();
                    }
                }); 
                wall.fitHeight($('#guide').height());
            });

            $(window).trigger("resize");
        });
});
```

Here is how it's actually coming out

[image: results]

Now I think the quality of the code is bad, I'm not sure every item should be a 'block' but this is the only way I can get it to work. I want the elements to stay grouped, however I'm sure this will break on different size screens.  Should the section containers be blocks, and the nested items level-1 as shown in the example?

2 things I'm stuck on

1. Gutter between sections, how can I add space between the section groups?
2. Section headers - ideally I want these to be 30px high but the background disapears when I do that in the CSS. I get that the freewall code is overwriting this, how can I set these heights differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Secret is in these numbers

data-gutterX=10 data-gutterY=10 data-cellW=0.5 data-cellH=0.5